# Drive Partitions not Extending

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, partition-recovery

I have a USB stick which I made into a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu, and then I formatted the USB stick. However, it only has 2MB of space on it, however it is an 8GB USB.

I found the reason for this problem in *diskmgmt.msc*, the Windows Drive Partition tool. It had a 2MB Partition and two other partitions which were 6.52GB and 758MB. They are both unallocated however when I right click on the 2MB Partition the extend volume is blanked out and I cannot click on it.

If I right click on the other 2 Partitions, the only options available are *New Spanned Volume, New Striped Volume and New Mirrored Volume*.

Is there any way to piece these 3 Partitions back together? Is there any software to solve this problem?

If you need any additional information, if I have phrased something wrongly or if you need any other information relating to this question, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often difficult to manipulate partitions through The Windows Drive Manager because of the way the Operating System tracks and uses the partition logs during run-time operations. [Think file deletion while file in use] exception.

> You can use free partition utilities such as [Mini Tool Partition
>   Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/download.html) or you can correct
>   the issues manually via the Windows built in
>   [DISKPART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) command line utility
>   by following a support
>   [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) .